# saving imagepath in database and changing background image

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

1. First problem .I want to save image path in database but we have an error "String or binary data would be truncated.The statement has been terminated".
2. Second problem is that background image is not changing.

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;

public partial class welcome : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    string fname;
    string fpath;
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
    SqlCommand cmd;
    string emailname;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if ((Session["Username"] == null) && (Session["useraddress"] == null))
        {
            Response.Redirect("Registration.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
            emailname = Session["useremail"].ToString();
            Label2.Text = Session["Username"].ToString();
            Label3.Text = Session["useraddress"].ToString();
            welcomelbl.Text = Session["Username"].ToString();
            addlbl.Text = Session["useraddress"].ToString();
        }
    }

    protected void Button1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session.Clear();
        Response.Redirect("login.aspx");
    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        imageupload();
    }
    public  void imageupload()
    {
fpath = FileUpload2.PostedFile.FileName;

            if ((string.IsNullOrEmpty(fpath)))
            {
                return;
            }
            fname = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fpath);
            FileUpload2.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/"+emailname+"/")+fname); 
            imagepathtext.Text = Server.MapPath("~/"+emailname+"") + fname;
            imgnametext.Text = fname;
            divimg.Style.Add("background-image", "url("+fname+")");
SqlConnection con = Connection.conn(); 
         con.Open();
         SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into imgtbl (imgname,useraddress,imgaddress) values(@name ,'" + emailname + "' ,@imgaddress)", con);
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", imgnametext.Text).ToString(); ;
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@imgaddress",imagepathtext.Text).ToString();
         cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
         con.Close();
         return;
}
}
```

Comment: 1st Problem: one of your fields is too short in the database.

Comment: tank you sir i had solved first problem.please sir solve my second problem

Comment: If this is really how your code looks thats your first problem, if your in Visual Studio please press ctrl + k & ctrl + d and update your answer

Answer (score 0):

Ist Problem `Example`

This problem because of you may declared column `datatype varchar(25)` but while inserting data more than 25 characters in that column.

Check your datatype length

For second problem specify your image path like this

```
string fname = @"C:\imagepath";
fpath = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fname);
```

Comment: some on says use this '<%# url("imagepaht", "{0}") %>' but i am confuse howwe can use

Answer (score 0):

1. 1st Problem is due to short length of the datatype in database then data. Change your datatype accordingly.
2. 2nd problem is due to syntax I think. Change your code in function imageupload like:

   divimg.Style.Add("background", "url("+imagepath+")");

Comment: sir i am also trying that but there is no change except my previous image that become hide hide

Comment: Check the image file path in firebug.